# Python missing argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

Where is my fault

"this code is only part of my code
I just copied part of it"

```
import turtle

wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Pacman")
wn.setup(900,700)
class Pacman(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("yellow")
        self.penup()
        self.speed(0)
    def up(self):
        self.goto(self.xcor(),self.ycor()+24)
    def down(self):
        self.goto(self.xcor(),self.ycor()-24)
    def left(self):
        self.goto(self.xcor()-24,self.ycor())
    def right(self):
        self.goto(self.xcor()+24,self.ycor())

wn.listen()
wn.onkey(Pacman.down, "Down")
wn.onkey(Pacman.up, "Up")
wn.onkey(Pacman.right, "Right")
wn.onkey(Pacman.left, "Left")
wn.tracer(0)

while True:
   wn.update()
```

Fail

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__

return self.func(*args)

File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\turtle.py", line 686, in eventfun

fun()
TypeError: up() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

When I click Right,Down,Up or Left Button square not moving and in console writing this fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Pacman" is a class template, so you can't call methods on it like that. You should either create a Pacman object (like so):

```
new_pacman = Pacman()
```

And then you could run your functions like so:

```
new_pacman.up()
```

Or (if I'm not mistaken) you could try this, which I *think* should also work:

```
Pacman().up() which
```

Answer (score 0):

do `pacman_instance = Pacman()` right before `wn.listen()`

The issue is that you're trying to do an operation on a class rather than an instance of the class

Answer (score 0):

If you just add `Pacman = Pacman()` before the line `wn.listen()`, it'll work!

The issue is you're trying to access a class that was not instantiated, and with this line you create this instance, and everything will work perfectly ;)